Do any recursive field extensions of this field not have a recursive sequence of increasing degree?
Let $F$ be the field $\mathbb{Q}(\{\sqrt{p_n}:n\in K\})$ where $K$ is the halting set and $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number.  $F$ is the standard example of a recursive field without a splitting algorithm.
My question is, does there exist a recursive field $E$ which is an infinite algebraic extension of $F$ such that there exists no recursive sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $E$ such that the degree of $x_n$ over $F$ is less than the degree of $x_{n+1}$ over $F$ for all $n$?

What is $p_n$? I would assume it's the $n$th prime, but then your $F$ is just $\mathbb{Q}$.

Perhaps you intended to take $\sqrt{p_n}$?

I'm also confused about the conclusion: the hypothesis about $E$ is universal. So if such $E$ exists, then $E=F$ works. (But maybe I'm misunderstanding something, my knowledge of computability theory is severely lacking...)

@NoahSchweber Sorry, I forgot the square root, I added it now.  And yes $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime.

@tomasz $F$ would not be an infinite algebraic extension of itself.
